# Get git commit from short hash using Github API

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have a short hash that should identify a commit on my repository. I'd like to use this to get the long hash, without having to use git locally (I'm aware I can do this using 'git show 918fe27', if I have a local copy of the repo, which I don't).

Say my hash is 918fe27:

> 1)https://github.com/$USER/$REPO/commit/918fe27 (works, but html response)
>
> 2)https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/git/commits/918fe2742c80b06661444857a34fcdb29c76df36 (works, but I don't have the full hash)

I'd like to use (2), but with only the short hash, but it seems that it just doesn't work that way, even though the non-api version of the same thing (1) works fine.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try `https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/commits/918fe27`

Example: https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/commits/abe6484

Docs: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I was using the method documented here:
http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit

Any idea what the difference is?

Comment: Those are just two different APIs. The one you were using is a low-level API for directly working with Git objects. The other one is a high-level API for working with repository commits (e.g. listing commits). One has support for short hashes, the other one doesn't. :)